# ASP ignore character

Tags: asp-classic

I am writing a classic ASP page. This line works:

```
Response.Write ("<tr>" & vbCrLf)
```

I want to add `onmouseover="this.style.backgroundColor='#ffff66';" onmouseout="this.style.backgroundColor='#d4e3e5';` to the text.

I tried this:

```
Response.Write ("<tr  onmouseover="this.style.backgroundColor='#ffff66';" onmouseout="this.style.backgroundColor='#d4e3e5';>" & vbCrLf)
```

But it causes ASP to think part is a comment. I am looking for the ignore char or the correct line of code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To escape quotes (") in VB write it twice.
In this case

```
Response.Write ("<tr onmouseover=""this.style.backgroundColor='#ffff66';"" onmouseout=""this.style.backgroundColor='#d4e3e5';"">" & vbCrLf)
```

(There was also a missing qoute after the last ; )

Answer (score 0):

Replace inner set of double quotes with double-double quotes:

`Response.Write ("<tr onmouseover=""this.style.backgroundColor='#ffff66';"" onmouseout=""this.style.backgroundColor='#d4e3e5';"">" & vbCrLf)`